# Polymer elements work with non polymer website?

Tags: polymer

Simple question but can I build a single page form using polymer that can be launched, through a CTA button, from a non polymer website?

I need this form to store the values in json format, and then populate a data table within my polymer web app by parsing that json data.

So  once I've got my polymer form page built, I'm going to wrap it inside of this CTA button that launches the page when clicked. This CTA needs to be distributed on multiple clients sites, so "third party" sites that I have no control over.

how could I bake in polymers required imports, so that it can run on their website?

Comment: As long as you have right imports, i don't see why it should not work

Comment: Victor, is there any issue you are facing?

Comment: @a1626 I understand what you're saying. I should have provided more context. 

So  once I've got my polymer form page built, I'm going to wrap it inside of this CTA button that launches the page when clicked. This CTA needs to be distributed on multiple clients sites, so "third party" sites that I have no control over.

I suppose what I should have asked, how could I bake in polymers required imports, so that it can run on their website?

Comment: Can you edit your question to be more descriptive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have all the necessary imports inlcuding Polymer inside your form element. But there are two files that you'll have to import in your CTA button

1. Your form element
2. Polyfill webcomponent-lite

There are two ways in which you can achieve having all Polymer files accessible to you in your element

1. You can use `cdn` to call to files like polymer.html
2. Better method will be to `vulcanize` all the required files including your element into one file (or two one for html and one for js if you use crisper also) so that there is no load on client side to fetch resources.

`Webcomponent-lite.min.js` you'll have to keep outside of your vulcanized file.

So, so far you'll have to export a package of 3-4(CTA button, webcomponents-lite, your vulcanized element) files minimum to your client.

This should do the trick.